# How to iterate over all pages to scrape the data (using selenium and scrapy) and save it in excel file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

```py
while True:
    try:
        next_page=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_cfiftp"]/a[@aria
        label="Next page"]')
        sleep(5)
        next_page.click()
        sleep(5)
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        find_places=sel.xpath('//*[@class="_1wz0grtk"]/a[1]/@href |'
                                    '//*[@class="_1oajdzlk"]/a[1]/@href').extract()
        for place in find_places:
            url='https://www.airbnb.co.in'+place
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse_city)
            sleep(10)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.logger.info('No more pages to load.')
        sleep(10)
        self.driver.quit()
        break

    def parse_city(self,response):
          sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
          Name=response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="name"]//h1//text() |'
                                    '//h1//text()[1]').extract()
         yield{'Name':Name}
```

*This is my block of code. I am unable to pass the url to parse_city()
I want to scrape details from various pages
I am using selenium and scrapy *

Comment: Is the response's url what you want to scrape?

Comment: the output of this      **url='https://www.airbnb.co.in'+place**

Comment: Can you print the value of url?

Comment: yes the url value is right and i can print it; but I am not getting the other fields.